# SwiftUI configure LazyVGrid with no spacing

Tags: swift, swiftui, lazyvgrid

I wanted to create a grid of cells with no spaces or smaller space just like the Photos app, is it possible with SwiftUI 2 LazyVGrid? I've tried it but there is always this space in-between columns.

In the documentation, the `spacing` parameter is described as:

> spacing
> The spacing beween the grid and the next item in its parent view.

Which doesn't make much sense, can't you just use `padding` for that? Also, when I tried increasing the spacing, it seems to be actually impacting the space in-between rows of cells, which is even more unexpected.

Answer (score 120):

You give `spacing: 0` in `LazyVGrid` for vertical spacing, and `spacing: 0` in `GridItem` for horizontal spacing.

Here is a demo. Tested with Xcode 12 / iOS 14

[image: demo]

```
struct TestImagesInGrid: View {
    @State private var imageNames: [String]

    private let threeColumnGrid = [
        GridItem(.flexible(minimum: 40), spacing: 0),
        GridItem(.flexible(minimum: 40), spacing: 0),
        GridItem(.flexible(minimum: 40), spacing: 0),
    ]

    init() {
        _imageNames = State(initialValue: (0..<8).map { _ in
            "image_\(Int.random(in: 1...3))"
        })
    }

    var body: some View {
        LazyVGrid(columns: threeColumnGrid, alignment: .leading, spacing: 0) {
            ForEach(imageNames.indices) { i in
                Image(imageNames[i]).resizable()
                    .aspectRatio(1, contentMode: .fill)
                    .border(Color.black)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Exactly what I'm looking for! The docs was misleading on the Grid. Your wording is much more clearer. The docs for GridItem: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/griditem

Answer (score 1):

Short answer:

```
GridItem(.flexible(), spacing: 0),
```