# How to make a LazyVGrid of square images?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

How I can make a square image similar to the photo gallery?

I'm trying the following:

```
let columns: [GridItem] = [
  GridItem(.flexible()),
  GridItem(.flexible())
]

LazyVGrid(
    columns: columns,
    alignment: .center
) {
    ForEach(self.selectedImages, id: \.self) { image in
        Image(uiImage: image)
            .resizable()
            .scaledToFit()
            .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity, minHeight: 0, maxHeight: .infinity)
            .aspectRatio(1, contentMode: .fill)
            .background(Color.blue)
    }
}
```

However, this results in this:

[image]

I want to build a 2x2 square grid (similar to this 3x3 below - I want the images to fit nicely into the square)

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/a/63027052/12299030?

Comment: Actually that did not worked for me :(

It works if I use a geometryReader to set a width and height, but that seems kind of much right?

Answer (score 21):

Try this.  It provides the correct aspect ratio and properly clips the images to fill a square:

```
ForEach(self.selectedImages, id: \.self) { image in
    Color.blue
        .aspectRatio(1, contentMode: .fill)
        .overlay(
            Image(uiImage: image)
                .resizable()
                .scaledToFill()
        ).clipped()
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I was struggling to keep `AsyncImage`s square in my `LazyVGrid` and wrapping it in a Color like this seems a better workaround than the alternatives I've seen that invoke combinations of `GeometryReader` and frame manipulation.

Feels like it should be a simple configuration to force an aspect ratio in a LazyXGrid layout so I worry I'm misusing the view somehow. But that is now a concern for a slower day.

Comment: This answer works but what's actually going on here? Is there some magic to the color blue? Can it be another view?

Comment: The `Color.blue` just serves as the base view and provides the frame for the image.  The color doesn't matter since it will be overlayed by the image.  I usually use `Color.clear`.  `.scaledToFill()` will cause some of the image to go outside of the `Color.blue` square, and `.clipped()` removes that overhang.

Answer (score 2):

I found this to be effective:

```
Image(uiImage: image)
            .resizable()
            .aspectRatio(1, contentMode: .fill)
            .clipped()
```

when used with a `LazyVGrid` and a `columns` value of

```
let columns = [GridItem(.adaptive(minimum: 80))]
```